# Clustering with Parametric distance in terms of error

Tags: clustering, optimization, constraint

I want to solve a constraint-based clustering problem. The constraint is a function of the points in one cluster. In simpler terms, I want to divide the data points into two clusters (A and B), such that it satisfies 
$$\sum_i \: f(A_i) \le \text{constant}.$$
Also, I want to have fixed number of points in A.

I tried searching so much but couldn't find solution. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You probably need to look into optimization rather than clustering.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I formulated the problem in terms of KNN classification to obtain the clusters